# Copy and replace while keeping signs within brackets belonging to the search term

Tags: python, replace

I need to replace thousands of matches in a source code file.
Does anyone know how to replace `"bar"` with `"foo"` while exchanging the brackets and keeping what's inside?
This is how the copy and replace should work:

```
    int v = -bar[0].fZ;
    int v = -bar[123].fZ;
```

replace with:

```
    int v = -foo.foo(0).fZ;
    int v = -foo.foo(123).fZ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

code_content = '''
    int v = -bar[0].fZ;
    int v = -bar[123].fZ;
'''

code_content = re.sub(r'(\-)(bar)\[(\d+)\](?=\.\w+)', r'\1foo.foo(\3)', code_content, re.M)
print(code_content)
```

The output:

```
    int v = -foo.foo(0).fZ;
    int v = -foo.foo(123).fZ;
```

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 1):

[`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) allows you to precisely match strings and reuse the matched groups in a substitution:

you can capture the number in a named group (`(?P<number>\d+)`) and reference it in the substitution with `\g<number>`:

```
import re

text = '''int v = -bar[0].fZ;
int v = -bar[123].fZ;
'''

print(re.sub('int\ v\ =\ -(?P<bar>\w+)\[(?P<number>\d+)\]\.fZ;',
             'int v = -foo.foo(\g<number>).fZ;', text))
```

which prints:

```
int v = -foo.foo(0).fZ;
int v = -foo.foo(123).fZ;
```

you are free to name and reference more groups (i also named `<bar>` which is a bit pointless here as i don't reference it in the substitution...).